# Why is the CollectionView function called twice in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am having trouble with the function being called 2 times. Because of this, the value in PageView is not set properly because the index value is not correct. How can you control this correctly?

**ViewController.swift**

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var pageView: UIPageControl!
    @IBOutlet var guideView: UIView!
    var step : Int! = 0
    var beforeStep : Int! = 0

    var imageArray = [UIImage(named: "swipe1"),
                      UIImage(named: "swipe2"),
                      UIImage(named: "swipe3"),
                      UIImage(named: "swipe4"),
                      UIImage(named: "swipe5")]


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        pageView.numberOfPages = imageArray.count
        pageView.currentPage = 0
        pageView.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.color(.dacColor)
        pageView.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.gray
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(252.0/255.0), green: CGFloat(251.0/255.0), blue: CGFloat(245.0/255.0), alpha: CGFloat(1.0))
        collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(252.0/255.0), green: CGFloat(251.0/255.0), blue: CGFloat(245.0/255.0), alpha: CGFloat(1.0))
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return imageArray.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        if let vc = cell.viewWithTag(111) as? UIImageView {
            vc.image = imageArray[indexPath.row]
        }
        if let ab = guideView.viewWithTag(222) as? UIPageControl {
            ab.currentPage = indexPath.row - 1
        }
        return cell
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let size = collectionView.frame.size
        return CGSize(width: size.width, height: size.height)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }
}
```

**problematic function part**

```swift
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        if let vc = cell.viewWithTag(111) as? UIImageView {
            vc.image = imageArray[indexPath.row]
        }
        if let ab = guideView.viewWithTag(222) as? UIPageControl {
            ab.currentPage = indexPath.row - 1
        }
        return cell
    }
```

**CollectionView in StoryBoard**

[image]

**View List in Storyboard**

[image]

> I want the PageController to be marked to match the location of the picture.

Has anyone solved the same problem as me?

Comment: u need to put the UIPageControl out of the collection view (in main View) and when you scroll you need to find the index using the scroll delegate

Comment: @SiddhantNigam I updated the picture to the question. As you can see, the PageController is not in the CollectionView.

Comment: @SiddhantNigam  How should I use the scroll delegate? Show me the answer.

Comment: try FSPagerView its easy : https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSPagerView try this if you don't like this then I will share you the code of collection view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)` is a collection view delegate method which tends to get called more than once, and there are a lot of factors that trigger the call like:

1. The number of visible cells you've got, depending on the height of the collection
2. When scrolling through cells to reuse them

Or triggers to change/refresh the collection like:

3. `reloadData()`, `reloadItems(at:)` or `reloadSections(_:)`
4. Perhaps a `layoutIfNeeded()` call from the view that contains this collection view.

and more...

The point is, the function getting called more than once is pretty normal. Your answer probably lies in "What triggers the call?"

**EDIT**:

To update your pageControl according to the index of the collection:

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
   let visibleRect = CGRect(origin: yourCollectionView.contentOffset, size: yourCollectionView.bounds.size)
   let midPointOfVisibleRect = CGPoint(x: visibleRect.midX, y: visibleRect.midY)
   if let visibleIndexPath = yourCollectionView.indexPathForItem(at: midPointOfVisibleRect) {
            yourPageControl.currentPage = visibleIndexPath.row
   }
}
```

If you're using a `UIPageViewController` just for the page indication, a [`UIPageControl`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipagecontrol) should do. You might also have to set `yourCollectionView.isPagingEnabled  = true` as that would be more appropriate for a page control.

Comment: Can't I control the PageController normally?

Comment: Okay, just saw your edited question. This was to explain the function call. So, you need to update the page control according to your collection view cell's index??

Comment: Yes, the PageController value must be set to match the index value of the picture.

Comment: Where should I use the function you added?

Comment: I've edited my answer to your needs. `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` is a scrollview delegate function that should be available for collection view too, since it extends a scroll view. Let me know if you face any issues

Comment: @hongdeveloper Somewhere close to your collection view delegate function would do...

Comment: @hongdeveloper I already set  isPagingEnabled. Thanks to you, I solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

In collection view go to layout and select custom:

```
class CustomCollectionViewFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout
{
override func targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset proposedContentOffset: CGPoint, withScrollingVelocity velocity: CGPoint) -> CGPoint
{
    if let collectionViewBounds = self.collectionView?.bounds
    {
        let halfWidthOfVC = collectionViewBounds.size.width * 0.5
        let proposedContentOffsetCenterX = proposedContentOffset.x + halfWidthOfVC
        if let attributesForVisibleCells = self.layoutAttributesForElements(in: collectionViewBounds)
        {
            var candidateAttribute : UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes?
            for attributes in attributesForVisibleCells
            {
                let candAttr : UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? = candidateAttribute
                if candAttr != nil
                {
                    let a = attributes.center.x - proposedContentOffsetCenterX
                    let b = candAttr!.center.x - proposedContentOffsetCenterX
                    if fabs(a) < fabs(b)
                    {
                        candidateAttribute = attributes
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    candidateAttribute = attributes
                    continue
                }
            }

            if candidateAttribute != nil
            {
                return CGPoint(x: candidateAttribute!.center.x - halfWidthOfVC, y: proposedContentOffset.y);
            }
        }
    }
    return CGPoint.zero
}
}
```

and then in delegate:

```
 func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    var visibleRect = CGRect()

    visibleRect.origin = Collections.contentOffset
    visibleRect.size = Collections.bounds.size

    let visiblePoint = CGPoint(x: visibleRect.midX, y: visibleRect.midY)

    guard let indexPath = Collections.indexPathForItem(at: visiblePoint) else { return }


    print(indexPath.item)

}
```

Comment: I don't know how to use the class you expanded in my code.

Comment: did you copying paste the class which I gave you ?

Comment: Yes, I made a file of the class you gave me and copied it.

Comment: now click on collectionView in storyBoard and there you will see layout by default it will be flow and then u click and select custom and then the textfield will be there in that write the class name and hit enter

Comment: that class will help you to scrolling centre  and  scrollViewDidEndDecelerating help you to get the index path after scrolling is done

Comment: I solved the problem with it because there is a simpler solution below. I haven't really tried, but thank you for your effort. In fact, I've voted for you too.